# How to wait for a resource using await / async

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I don't fully understand how all the .Net async programming concepts (await, async, awaiters, sync context, etc) work.

I am working with sockets and they require buffers for reading/writting operations and I want to have a BufferAllocator object that searches and returns buffers to be used by sockets. The point is when there is no enough memory available (the pool of buffers is empty) the applications should wait for a buffer and continue when a required amount of memory is available.

How can I implement that?

Ok, this is my homework (just a demo for simplicity, it is not my real code):

```
class Program
{
    private static BufferAllocator _allocator;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _allocator = new BufferAllocator(100);   // 100 bytes
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await _allocator.GetBufferAsync(40); // 100 - 40 = 60bytes
            await _allocator.GetBufferAsync(40); //  60 - 40 = 20bytes 
            await _allocator.GetBufferAsync(40); //  20 < 40 (wait)
            Console.WriteLine("Worked!");  // <-------+
        }); //                                        |
        Console.ReadKey(); //                         |
        _allocator.ReleaseBuffer(40); // after pessing a key, release 40 bytes
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

class BufferAllocator
{
    private int _availableBytes;
    private SemaphoreSlim _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

    public BufferAllocator(int bufferSize)
    {
        _availableBytes = bufferSize;
    }

    public async Task GetBufferAsync(int size)
    {
        while(_availableBytes < size)
            await _signal.WaitAsync();

        _availableBytes -= size;
    }

    public void ReleaseBuffer(int size)
    {
        _availableBytes += size;
        _signal.Release();
    }
}
```

Note: there will be several sockets reading and writting in parallel. Please, give me a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you actually implement an `async` construct yourself you should probably use `TaskCompletionSource`. Think of it as a signaling object. It has a `Task` property that you can return to your clients to `await` on asynchronously. And you update the task's status using the `TaskCompletionSource`'s methods (e.g. `SetResult`). This is how one side (the producer) "notifies" the other (the consumer of that specific task) it should resume.

You can of course use a built-in construct if it fits, like `SemaphoreSlim`, which is size based, or an `AsyncAutoResetEvent`.

Make sure you **never forget to complete your tasks** (with a result, an exception or cancellation). Otherwise you'll face the most unpleasant bugs/deadlocks.

Comment: I create a tcs and return its Taks property so the consumer will be notified when the SetResult is invoked, I got it. What I don't know is where to invoke the SetResult method. I mean, when my ReleaseBuffer method is called it should verify if there is available memory, am I right? If yes, and given the GetBufferAsync method could be called several times, where do I share the requested size value?

Comment: I'm having difficulty imagining how he would use `TaskCompletionSource` here. Isn't awaiting on an internal structure enough for his cause?

Comment: @lontivero @YuvalItzchakov You return a task when you don't have a buffer to return and you want the caller to wait. You end that task when you do have a buffer to return, so you "wake" the caller with the buffer. That could be when someone returns a buffer, or when you decided to create more. If the amount of buffers is always the same than you can use `SemaphoreSlim`. If it's dynamic, you'll need to use `TaskCompletionSource` directly.